# How to detect the column spelling error in Excel after combining data using Power Query

Tags: excel, automation, powerquery

In the snapshots below, I have got 3 sheets and a Master sheet. I am going to use Power Query to append the 3 sheets into the Master sheet. If you notice, there is a spelling error on the 3rd sheet (highlighted in yellow). The spelling of the column should be "Commission" but it is spelled as "Commision", which causes the creation of new column and the data gets inserted into this new column but in reality the data should be inserted in correctly spelled column "Commission".

So suppose if the new data gets added to one of the sheet or a new sheet is created with new data. Using POWER Query, I can just refresh the source and the data will automatically get appended.

But how to detect if any of the column is misspelled? And on which sheet is it exactly misspelled. Because if a column is misspelled a new column will get created. And  the data will get inserted into wrong column

There can be many columns and sheets, going through every sheet and column will consume more time.

Is there a way to detect exactly on which sheet any of the column is misspelled ?

NOTE: 'The commission' column is just an example. Any of the column can be misspelled.

[Sheet 1, Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybUFF.png)

[Sheet 3, Master Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfwcZ.png)

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please toggle checkmark to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

If all the columns can have odd spellings on each tab then just discard the column titles so they become Column1 and Column2 etc, then rename them later after the combine

To get rid of titles, transform, Use headers as first row then remove first row